# Reading from file in producer/consumer model

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm trying to read a string from a file, do an HTTP request with that string, and if the request returns a 200 then do another HTTP request with it.

I thought a good model for this would be the producer consumer model, but for some reason I'm totally stuck. The whole process just stops at a certain point for some reason and I have no idea why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    ArrayBlockingQueue<String> subQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(3000000);

    ThreadPoolExecutor consumers = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10));
    ThreadPoolExecutor producers = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000000));
    consumers.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    String fileName = "test";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String address = new JSONObject(line).getString("Address");
            producers.submit(new Thread(() -> {
                if (requestReturn200(address)) {
                    try {
                        subQueue.put(address);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error producing.");
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        producers.shutdown();
    }

    while (subQueue.size() != 0 || !producers.isShutdown()) {
        String address = subQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (address != null) {
            consumers.submit(new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Doing..." + address);
                    doOtherHTTPReqeust(address);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Fatal error consuming);
                }
            }));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Null");
        }
    }

    consumers.shutdown();
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `   while (subQueue.size() != 0 || !producers.isShutdown()) {`  is this supposed to wait for producers to complete?

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor consumers = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10));
Why would you need 100 threads in pool while you got queue for 10 tasks only?

Comment: @Antoniosss It's supposed to make sure that it runs while the producer is still running. I increased the blocking size and changed it to ```!producers.isTerminated()``` and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This wont work, because `isShotdown()` returns `true` when you invoke `producers.shutdown()`. As code flow shows, this loop is after shutdown call so this always be true (and false cuz of !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while (subQueue.size() != 0 || !producers.isShutdown()) {
```

First of all `!producers.isShutdown()` will always return `!true` because it is checked after `producers.shutdown()`. `isShutdown` does not says if tasks in pool are still running or not, but if pool has been shut down, resulting in inability to accept new tasks. In your case this will always be `false`

Second, `subQueue.size() != 0` While your consumer creating loop and consumers takes much more faster data from queue than producers can provide, in middle of "producing" process, consumers might have clear the quueue resulting in condition `subQueue.size!=` to be falsy. As you know this would break the loop and forbit submition of producers.

You should stop using `queue.size()` but rather use blocking properties of `BlockingQueue`. `queue.take()` will block until new element is available.

So the overall flow should be like that.

1. Start some pool of producer tasks, like you are doing right now.
2. Let producer put data in blocking queue - yep you are here
3. Start some (I would say fixed) number of consumers
4. Let consumers `queue.take()` data from queue. This will force consumers to "autowait" for new data and take it when it will become available.

I will put aside mentions that creating 200 threads is insane and misses the whole purpose of multithreading consumers/producers/task pools, at least in your case IMHO. The idea is to use small amount of threads as they are heavyweight to do plenty of queued tasks. But that is discussion for different time .